# How do you stop an AWS-ECS-Task after it has completed its task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have deployed a ECS-Task, which makes a Backup of a Database. After this is done, the task remains in run status. Does anyone have an idea how to end the task ? 
 
 I use a Docker Container(Spring Boot) and I deploy the task with Terraform.

EDIT:
My Terraform looks like that:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                   = "${var.application_name}"
  container_definitions    =  "${data.template_file.container_definition_tpl.rendered}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/app_execution_role"
  task_role_arn            = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/app_task_role"
  cpu                      = 256
  memory                   = 512
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "scheduled_task" {
  name                = "${var.name}_${var.environment}_scheduled_task"
  description         = "Run ${var.name}_${var.environment} task at a scheduled time rate (1 day)"
  schedule_expression = "cron(* 9 * ? *)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "scheduled_task" {
  target_id = "${var.name}_${var.environment}_scheduled_task_target"
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduled_task.name}"
  arn       = "${data.aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id}"
  role_arn  = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_events.arn}"

  ecs_target {
    task_count          =  1
    task_definition_arn = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn}"
    launch_type="FARGATE"
    platform_version="LATEST"


    network_configuration {
      assign_public_ip = false
      security_groups= [data.aws_security_group.ecs_security_group.id]
      subnets =data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnet_ids.ids
    }
  }
```

I have a scheduled Task which runs once a day. But it creates a new Task and the other task is still RUNNUNG, so i would have 7 task after one week.

Comment: How are you deploying the ECS task? Can you share all the relevant parts of your code as a [mcve] so we can see what you've tried so far please?

Comment: Are you exiting from your backup program when the backup is competed, or it keeps running?

Comment: The program continues. Would a System.exit() be enough to stop the task ?

Comment: As long as the process is PID 1 or the PID 1 will exit if that exits then yes. If you have something else running as PID 1 that lives long term and launches the process that exits then no. But you can test that by running the container locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end the solution was very simple.
**Problem:**
The task ran in an ECS-Serivce and was also called as scheduled-event. This caused a lot of problems, because the task ran twice at given times. 
**Solution**:
In the end, the solution was to remove the ECS service because the job did not meet the requirements of an ECS service. The answer was to call the task only via the Schedules task. In addition, the implementation had to shut down the container, which ensured that when the task was completed, the task would close automatically and no unnecessary tasks would be there.

Comment: "the implementation had to shut down the container" - how did you do this?

Comment: @lucas I have the same problem, Can you illustrate how you solve it?

Comment: @channaly I had a simple SpringBoot-App and after the service, which should save certain data at a specified time, was finished, I used a ```System.exit();``` to terminate the program. This is how the task was Stopped in the cluster. Does it answer your question?

Comment: In order for a task to stop, container needs to exit, and for that the program/command that runs in the container just needs to exist with a status code 0.